# It seems that i dont have wsl2 on my pc but i did the right thing

Tags: linux, kali-linux, openvpn

i wanted to have wsl2 on my pc with kali linux, i downloaded kali linux and it works but when i try to open openvpn with my ovpn file, it said "dev net tun not find", i suggest
that im in wsl1, but look at my screen, i dont really think that im in wsl2. Look the image, my command isnt found.[image]

i followed this tutorial and i did all like them, i installed wsl_updatex64 to get wsl2 and i dont have difficulties in Kali Linux.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please add more details to your question how exactly you installed WSL and Linux. The problem shown in your screenshot is a question about Windows, not about Unix or Linux. If you have difficulties in Kali Linux, I suggest to start with a more user-friendly distribution like Ubuntu. See https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: Also please post error messages in english. You have a far higher chance of getting a satisfactory answer that way